# Flex video player help dynamically load video with php?

Tags: php, apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder

I need to load dynamiclly video in flex video player on the web,I'm using standard video player component,when page load a want to load a video in it.I'm not flex programmer,can someone help me with this?Tnx.

Comment: Do you have access to the .mxml file?

Comment: I will put all stuff on my web server,so yes I have,is there some good step by step tutorial,or can you explain me? Sorry on my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of video you want to view? If you want to load video over http, you must to specify url of this video in mxml, like this:

```
<s:VideoPlayer source="**your video url**" />
```

Comment: I upload an video on server,than later users can watch that video using my player,simple,is there some tutorial how to do this?I'm not Flex programmer,so any step by step tutorial will be great.